# Java error - .class expected

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying to create a program that read the input of name and mark of students then give out the name and grade of that student in the form GUI output but keep having the problem when compiling.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class p
{ 

private static String getGrade(int mark)
{
    String grade;
    if (mark<50)
                grade="F";
              else if (mark<65)
                grade="P";
              else if (mark<75)
                grade="C";
              else if (mark<85)
                grade="D";
              else
                grade="HD";
     return grade;
}
public static void main (String []args)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to the Mark Entry System");
    String studentName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter student name:");    
    int mark =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter mark for student (out of 100)"));
    String grade = getGrade(int mark);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The grade for " + studentName + " is " + grade);

}
}
```

Comment: suppose `String grade = getGrade(mark);` in the main class. please share the exception or stacktrace.

Comment: Not sure I understand your questions because I just start programming for a while. I just use Bluej for programming as well as compiling

Comment: @AnhMinhTran what's the error ?

Comment: @Shashwat just that " '.class' expected"

Comment: @AnhMinhTran No. There is no such compilation error as '.class expected`. What does it *really* say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
String grade = getGrade(int mark); //Can't do this
```

Pass some `int` like

```
String grade = getGrade(mark); //pass any integer you want
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Can you explain to me what's the logic behind this changes.

Comment: `String grade = getGrade(mark);` according to your code shared.(+1)

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhh, I would upvote for you twice if I could